# Sub-resources of the resource. Is this a valid REST?

Tags: rest

I want to expose some portion of my big REST resource as another resource (sub-resource). Is it valid to do so? What problems are possible with this approach? Is there a better way?

For example, I have a collection of computers. Each computer in this collection (main resource) have it's own sub-parts (sub-resources).

- /api/computers/117/chassis
- /api/computers/117/motherboard
- /api/computers/117/cpu

Where `computers` is the collection and `chassis`, `motherboard` and `cpu` are sub-resources of computer **#117**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. You can have problems when you want to access only resources like a specific type of CPU, but it's okay if you have also /api/cpus/123